# Enabling exceptions in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, gcc, exception

I have enabled `GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS`, `GCC_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS`, `GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS` in my XCode project. When I add the following lines of code to my source my program crashes with the forrlowing error: `terminate called throwing an exceptionProgram received signal:  “SIGABRT”.`:

```
   try {
    throw 1;
}
catch (...) {
    // handle
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to catch this exception? Do I have to do something more?

Comment: Where have you set these properties? In the project, or in the target? Target sometimes overrides project properties

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/262900-exception-results-in-sigabrt.html) may help. From the information there, my thought would be either the `-fexcpetions` parameter is not explicitly passed, or your file is not being recognised as C++ source (`.mm`/`.cpp`).